# Angular2: declare vars for all components

Tags: angular, inheritance, components

I'm using a company-wide internally hosted js-library. I referenced the script in the index.html file. To get it working I used the "declare" keyword in my root component to initialize some stuff when the app loads:

```
declare const someInternalLibrary: any;
```

Now, in another component I'd like to use the same library to do some other stuff.
How can I use it without repeating the upper line of code? That wouldn't be too clean I think. Is there something like inheritance for child-components? I read something about declarations, as I'm very new to ng2 I don't really see the way through though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may utilize `typings` definition in your application to declare your internal library.

If you are using `angular-cli` there is a typings.d.ts file there you may add all custom declarations. even you may define all your functions from the internal library which will then give you `intellisense`.

To read more how to write Declaration file you may look [here  (Writing Declaration Files)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/writing-declaration-files.html)

Comment: The const's working, thanks!
I don't really get the part with the functions or rather how to do it. I don't think it's just pasting all the stuff in the typings.d.ts... :D Do you have any references on this?

Comment: For functions you just have to declare definitions , not entire implementation, the link I have shared has details on how to write them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with Dependency injection tokens (Non-class dependencies or OpaqueToken)

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html#!#dependency-injection-tokens